# Configure HTML5 progress bar with jQuery Ajax

Tags: html, jquery, html5-canvas

I am using following code to make a ajax request. But how to configure **value** attribute when it is receiving the response.

```
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        cache:false,
        type:'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data:'json',
        beforeSend:function(x){
            $('#main').html("<progress id='bar' value='0' max='100'></progress>").show();
        },
        success:function(json){
            $('#bar').val(100);
            parseResponse(json);
        },
        complete:function(){

            $('#bar').hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// ...
beforeSend:function(x){
        $('#main').html("<progress id='bar' value='0' max='100'></progress").show();
        // the attribute name is value, not val ↑ 
},
success: function(json){
    $('#bar').val(100);
    alert(json);
    parseResponse(json);
},
// ...
```

See [`<progress>` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/progress) and [jQuery `.val()` API docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xTSHL/

Comment: It didn't work for me. I have tried to replace html5 progressbar to a div but no luck.

Comment: Apologies - I misread the question, and thought you were using jQuery UI. See my edit.

Comment: It's still not working. I have updated my code with latest input.

Comment: I added a working demo. If I had to guess, it's because `'json'` is not actually valid JSON.

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of a progress bar since it goes from 0 to 100 percent doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying: `$('#bar').attr('value', '100');`

If that doesn't work then it could be something to do with the fact that your `progress` element is being created dynamically.